# In android, I am not able to create a folder or save the log details in a specific file when using serilog.sinks.RollingFile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, serilog

To get error log details in the xamarin project i installed `serilog.sinks.xamarin` nuget package in my project. In android, I tried `serilog.sinks.rollingfile` to store the log details in the documents folder. This is my code

```
Log.Logger=new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(Environment.DirectoryDocuments,"AndroidErrorLog.txt"))
.WriteTo.AndroidLog().CreateLogger();
```

After executing the project, if I check the documents folder no file are created and no logs details are found. Can any one tell what mistake I have done and how to fix this issue?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "JCA_log-{Date}.txt")
                , outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.AndroidLog()
                .CreateLogger();
```

Taken from PhillipOGorman from the following sources:

- [Example #1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/228619#Comment_228619)
- [Example #2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23832/logging-with-xamarin-pcl)

I had this exact issue. I think it was something in the constructor that seemed to stop Serilog from creating a file.

Note #1: The Serilog code provided relies on the Sinks.File and Sinks.Xamarin.Droid Serilog libraries.

Note #2: He used: 
`Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath` 
when referencing where the file would write to but, 
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` 
works fine (plus it packages it within your apps sandbox.)